# Where clause completed from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I want to do something like this:

```
Select *
from a
where something = 123 and (Select clause from table where id = 1)
```

The clause is the completion of the where clause since it can be dinamic, it depends on the id, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: [Dynamic SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)??

Comment: With dynamic SQL, sure. But [that's not to be done lightly](http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). Embedding SQL in your tables is an especially iffy idea, since injection is a constant threat. There are [other ways](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) to implement dynamic search conditions. If at all possible, *don't* have dynamic search conditions -- you can store values and limits as columns as well.

Comment: What's the source of the `clause` data? Because anything that works here (almost certain to be dynamic SQL) is almost certainly going to be at risk of SQL Injection. So first thing you should ask, before "how can I do this?" should be "is this design *safe*?"

Comment: Maybe it's possible to include all possible subqueries in the `WHERE` clause an use Boolean logic or `CASE`s to control when, depending on the ID, they take effect. But to answer that i a more detailed way, you'd need to elaborate on your question and comprehensively describe what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `execute` for executing dynamic query  as below

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(1000) ='' 

SET @query = 'Select * from a where something = 123 and (' 
             + (SELECT clause 
                FROM   [table] 
                WHERE  id = 1) 
             + ')' 

EXECUTE @query
```

Comment: `INSERT [table] (id, clause) VALUES (1, '1 = 1); drop table a; shutdown with nowait')`.

Comment: I can encrypt the data column and they wont be able to do that